# How to return output variable of exec command back to client in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, exec

Let's take this sample application from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973974/meteor-js-simulate-server-command-line-on-client-html/23975340#23975340), it's let you run terminal and insert output once it's executed into the collection. I'm wondering what the solution could be, to return variable with result on client without using collections?

```html
<head>
  <title>terminal</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <input type="text" id="command">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

```js
Replies = new Meteor.Collection('replies');


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.events({
    'click #button': function () {
      var cmd = $("input#command").val();
      console.log("command", cmd);
      var replyId = Meteor.call('command', cmd);
      Session.set('replyId', replyId);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;
  Meteor.methods({
    'command' : function(line) {
      console.log("In command method", line);
      Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
      exec(line, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('Command Method', error, stdout, stderr);
        Fiber(function() {
          Replies.remove({});
          var replyId = Replies.insert({message: stdout ? stdout : stderr});
          return replyId;  
        }).run();
      }); 
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: didn't I already answer that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351610/return-variable-back-from-server-to-client-function-with-delay-in-meteor

Comment: if you want to use a Fiber instead of execSync, then you need to wrap the exec into a Fiber, not it's callback functions.

Comment: I tried execSync but got error half the time, bc execSync ran out. This solution with Collection works, but there has to be something better.

Comment: How the wraping of exec into Fiber would exactly looked like? Thanks for helping Christian.

Comment: Found working example here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753637/meteor-callback-to-sys-exec-inside-a-meteor-call-callback

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark a question as solved. To do this, we prefer answers below, rather than title [solved] hacks. Since this question is on hold, you could add an answer to the duplicate instead? Thanks!